# Is this a reasonable way to drive an H-bridge?

Tags: power, mosfet, motor, dc-motor, h-bridge

I currently need to drive a 400W (12-48V) DC motor via an H bridge.

Therefore, I set out to think of a way to drive the motor itself and came up with something like this:

[image: my schematic]

I use drivers to drive the two sides of the bridge and Q5 to modulate the voltage (via PWM) in the bridge. U4 and U5 are logic ports of type NOT.
C3 and R4 and R6 and C2 were placed to provide a delay to mitigate the delaying effect of the not port, but I'm not really sure if this makes sense or not.

I would like to ask if the method I have architected is acceptable or if there are any problems.

Comment: Looks like that gate driver does not have bootstrapping. How do you expect it to properly drive those top N-FET's?

Comment: By boostrapping do you mean "synchronizing" the two signals so the mosfets don't short circuit?

Comment: No, a bootstrap circuit maintains a proper gate-source voltage to keep the top N-FET's fully on as the source voltage rises vs. ground. You currently have a source follower, not a switch.

Comment: Texas Instruments has some excellent documents explaining Gate drivers, I suggest you read: https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slua618a/slua618a.pdf Section 5.2 explains how to deal with driving an NMOS-only stage.

Comment: there are better FET drivers out there that will provide the boost circuit that @Unimportant mentions.  Also, no need to PWM the voltage source with Q5, just pwm the drive signals to the FETs themselves.

Comment: This will need VDRIVE  at least 10V more than VMOT ... or change to a bootstrap scheme per other comments.

Comment: 100% get an all-in-one H-bridge chip.    If those two drivers aren't perfectly synchronized, you could be witness to quite the fireworks show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a bootstrapped H bridge driver circuit that should work OK: -

[image]

Image taken from [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/tahmids-h-bridge-does-it-work/545100).

Focus on this part: -

[image]

C1, C2 and D1 create a voltage at VB that is several volts higher than the 12 volt supply and, this ensures that MOSFET Q1 can receive a proper gate-source voltage and turn the MOSFET on into full conduction. Output HO will switch to a high level of 12 volts plus several more volts in order to properly activate Q1.

Your circuit would burn the upper MOSFETs because the source has to be lower than the gate voltage and by maybe 4 or 5 volts thus, the upper MOSFETs would dissipate a lot of wasted power and fry.

You might also be aware now that the MOSFET that switches the upper supply is also going to have difficulties when VDRIVE is not significantly higher than VMOT. Similar story.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: "Having difficulties" is an understatement, and can never pull the motor up to the supply rail. Lasb3tas. This is true for all Nch Bridges